# Quickest way to write £ on US Keyboard?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, symbols

What's the quickest way to write the pound (£) sign on a US Keyboard?

Currently I use Alt+0163 but it's not very quick because my laptop doesn't have a number pad so I need to set num lock on.

Is there a better/quicker way?

The keyboard looks like this:

[image: US Keyboard]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use a product such as [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/) or [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to issue the pound character using a hotkey, maybe for example the (mostly) unused Scroll key.

Comment: I ended up using AutoHotKey. I use an auto replace on $$ to £.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>$</kbd>.

[image: US international keyboard layout]

Comment: I do not have this AltGr key you speak off. Neither of the alt keys will work for this combination.

Comment: AltGr is an abbreviation for Ctrl+ALt - available on (some?) European keyboards.

Comment: If on Windows, does Ctrl + Alt + Shift + $ work?

Comment: @Sblair that is a US International Keyboard. I updated my post with the keyboard I have at the same time as your posted your pic.

Comment: Yip it windows, but no Ctrl + Alt + Shift + $ doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried changing the keyboard layout setting in Windows, perhaps to United States-International, or even to UK?

Comment: Yeah good idea. I just did that by changing it to US International, and the RightAlt + Shift + $ works. It might be a little bit confusing, but I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

Use ALT-0163 (enter the digits on the numeric keypad).

```
£
```

(Character map will show the code to use, for that characters this method can be used for, on its status bar when the character is selected.)

Comment: Ray said that his keyboard doesn’t have a numeric keypad.

Comment: Read past the title.

Comment: Do'h: but most laptops have a function key that maps some of the main keyboard to a numeric keyboard. So then a matter of also holding down the function key *and* alt.